# Global composite operation in three.js

Tags: three.js, globalcompositeoperation

Globalcomposite are available in html5 canvas. Is it available in threejs? How to implement the destination out composite operation in three.js?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are using three.js ' `CanvasRenderers` you can use `globalCompositeOperation` as they are for `2d` contexts.
- If you are using a `webgl` context, basically everything is possible with shaders. As Shiladittya's comment states, three.js also provides [blending modes](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Constants/Materials) (see [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_blending)). They are available in the material property `blending`.

Comment: In three js there is a blending function which can support subtract , addition and custom blending.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty you're right, i editted my answer